# how to change particular pixels' color using inRange() for BGR values in OpenCV python

Tags: opencv, python-3.6

I have a grayscale image and want to change certain pixels into black colored ones using inRange() opencv python. Can anyone sugget how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

`inRange` will give you a mask. Apply that mask with a bitwise AND to only get the pixels that lie within the range you specified.

```
mask =  cv.inRange( img, lowerb, upperb)
imgMasked = cv.bitwise_and(img,mask)
```